# AngularJS - nginclude sidebar will dont have the function for the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i have build one web which include sidebar and the main content. I included the sidebar with `ng-include` , but the sidebar is not able to function.

```
<html>

<head>
    <link href="lepwww/css/maincss.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="dataController">

    <div class="main-container">
        <div ng-include="templates"></div>

    </div>


    <!-- Angular JS Scripts -->
    <script src="lepwww/css/angular-1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lepwww/css/angular-1.6.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lepwww/css/angular-1.6.1/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lepwww/css/angular-1.6.1/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lepwww/vendors/svg-assets-cache/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
    <script src="lepwww/vendors/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myapp", ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']);


        app.filter('startFrom', function () {
            return (input, start) => {
                start = +start; //parse to int
                return input.slice(start);
            }
        });
        app.controller("dataController", ["$scope", "$http", "$element",
            function ($scope, $http, $element) {
                $scope.templates = 'view/layout/sidebar.html';
            }

        ]);
    </script>

    <script src="lepwww/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lepwww/js/dialog/zebra_dialog.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="lepwww/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lepwww/js/test.js"></script>
    <script src="lepwww/js/utils.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If i copy direct the code to replace the nginclude, but able to function.

This is my sidebar code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 left_col">
    <div class="left_col scroll-view">
        <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
            <a href="console.html" class="site_title">
                <div class="profile_pic">

                    <img src="lepwww/images/lep_icon.png" alt="..." width="50" height="50">
                </div>
                <span>LEP-DMS</span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <!-- sidebar menu -->
        <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side main_menu" style=" margin-top:12px">
            <div class="menu_section">
                <h3>General</h3>
                <ul class="nav side-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home
                            <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="nav child_menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="console.html">Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <i class="fa fa-tv"></i> Inventory
                            <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="nav child_menu">
                            <li id="li_hardware">
                                <a href="hardware.html">Hardware</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="li_software" class="">
                                <a href="software.html">Software</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to include the javascript file inside also, still not working.
Tried the method to switch the jquery file and angularjs file(The position of javascript file changed, still not able to work).

Any idea how does this problem occur? Since i check the console also not found any error for this.
Thanks.

Comment: did you try `<div ng-include="'view/layout/sidebar.html'"></div>`

Comment: Yes, I tried this method also. But the sidebar still won't work.

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console about that html file? Or are you building the file into javascript?  Just looked at where we use ngInclude with a scope variable and we require the leading / in the path.  Without it we get a Console error stating the page can't be found.

Comment: I able to get the design show in the file, but the dropdown list are not able to function. The console are not showing any related error. @kendavidson

Comment: What are you using to control the drop downs, I see you're using angular-material, but you're not actually using the directives for <menu> that are provided.  Which of your JavaScript files are you expecting to control the drop downs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you couldn't find any error in console, that's mean either the code doesn't being trigger or the code being trigger but selector select nothing(it also could be selector undefined but well handle in your code snippet, that probably why it doesn't output undefined exception)

Next if it get trigger, check whether or not your sidebar javascript call before ng-include, simply use break point to verify.

If it is trigger before, you can simply a `<script>... <your js code to make sidebar work> ...</script>` under the end of your ng-include file. Manually call the function again, at this point, it should work since your html component appear in DOM.